# Some <td>'s Cannot Be Found by find_next()

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So this is a question about BS4 for scraping, I encountered scraping a website that has barely have any ID on the stuff that was supposed to get scraped for info, so I'm hellbent on using `find_next` `find_next_siblings` or any other iterator-ish type of BS4 modules.

The thing is I used this to get some td values from my tables so I used `find_next()`, it did work on some values but for some reason, for the others it can't detect it.

Here's the html:

```
<table style="max-width: 350px;" border="0">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td style="max-width: 215px;">REF. NO.</td>
        <td style="max-width: 12px;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right">000124 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>REF. NO.</td>
        <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>MANU</td>
        <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>STREAK</td>
            <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right">1075</td>
        </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td>PACK</td>
        <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right">1</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">ON STOCK. </td>
        </tr>
  .... and so on
```

So I used this code to get what I want:

```
div = soup.find('div', {'id': 'infodata'})
table_data = div.find_all('td')
for element in table_data:
  if "STREAK" in element.get_text():
        price= element.find_next('td').find_next('td').text
        print(price+ "price")
  else:
    print('NOT FOUND!')
```

I actually copied and paste suff from the HTML to make sure I didn't mistype anything, many times, but still it would always go to not found. But if i try other Table names, I can get them. For example that `PACK`

By the way, im using two `find_next()` there because the html has three `td`'s in every `<tr>`

Please I need your help, why is this working for some words while for some not. Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not print the tag instead of just `NOT FOUND!`, so you can see which td's it is and isn't finding?

Comment: I ran the code removing the `else` part and it is printing the price. Even with the else part, it prints the price, just in between many `NOT FOUND`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite it like this:

```
trs = div.find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.select('td')
    if len(tds) > 1 and 'STREAK' in tds[0].get_text().strip():
        price = tds[-1].get_text().strip()
```